# Count a variable in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I dont know what I am doing wrong here.  But I am trying to increment "Counter"

Code is supposed to loop backwards through 1000 then every 10 pause for 30 seconds.  I can't seem to get the COUNTER to work though.  There are a dozen Stack Overflows about this but I still can't figure out my mistake here

```
set counter=0

FOR /L %%G IN (1000,-1,1) DO (
    set /a "counter=%counter%+1"
start otherscript.cmd %%G
    echo For %%G
    echo Counter %counter%
        if %counter% ==10 (
        set /a counter=0
        timeout 30
        )
    )
```

Comment: I am kicking myself in the head over this issue.  This still only results in a 1 instead of a Zero constantly and now I get a missing operator at the end, not sure what thats about

'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set !counter!=0

FOR /L %%G IN (40298917,-1,1) DO (
 set /a !counter!=%counter%+1
 echo For %%G
 echo Counter %counter%
 pause
  if !counter! ==10 (
  set /a counter=0
  timeout 30
  )
 )
'

Comment: Use this: `set /a "counter+=1"` and `if "!counter!"=="10"`